# Smartphone racing bike mount

Tags: racing, smartphone-mount

I have a Samsung S Advance smartphone, and I want to mount it on my racing bike. The only bike mounts I can find are either iphone mounts, or a few universal bike mounts, but these are all too small to fit on a racing bike's handlebars or stem. (appr. 4cm in diameter).

I'm a good-weather biker, so I don't need a water-proof case or bag, just a mount, and preferably as small as possible.

I've tried strapping my phone to the stem with elastic straps, which worked, but I'm afraid the vibrations will damage the phone, or that it might fall off.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: What is the nature of your use? Using apps like strava and the like or using maps for navigation or something else?  When I go on long ride and want to record it. I just put my phone in a ziplock baggy and into my jersey pocket.

Comment: I want to use it for navigation.

Comment: Phones don't generally work well for navigation on your bike because they have very low visibility in sunlight.

Comment: Old question, but since it was asked the  "Wahoo RFLKT+" is now available.    http://au.wahoofitness.com/devices/rflkt.html   this device pairs with your phone and displays the numbers, and acts as a bluetooth/ANT+ bridge to link multiple sensors together.  Sadly it doesn't do navigation afaik.

Comment: @Kibbee older phones maybe, most modern flagships have excellent direct-sunlight visibility in my experience.